# Understanding color matrix of hue

Tags: math, graphics, matrix, colors, colormatrix

This is a color matrix in ARGB:

```
[

R,0,0,0,0,

0,G,0,0,0,

0,0,B,0,0,

0,0,0,A,0,

0,0,0,0,1

]
```

And I know its hue color matrix below:
(
refers to gskinner's source code:
http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/12/colormatrix_cla.html
)

```
define lr=0.213
define lg=0.715
define lb=0.072
define a=0.143
define b=0.140
define c=-0.283
define hueangle
define cos=cos(hueangle)
define sin=sin(hueangle)
```

---

```
[

lr+cos*(1-lr)+sin*(-lr),lg+cos*(-lg) +sin*(-lg),lb+cos(-lb) +sin*(1-lb),0,0,

lr+cos*(-lr)+ sin*(a),lg+cos*(1-lg)+sin*(b),lb+cos(-lb) +sin*(c),0,0,

lr+cos*(-lr)+ sin*(-(1-lr)),lg+cos*(-lg) +sin*(lg) ,lb+cos(1-lb)+sin*(lb),0,0,

0,0,0,1,0,

0,0,0,0,1

]
```

---

(Thanks son_of_fire for pointing out the inexplicitness of the questions in the last edition.)

***Question***

- What formulas led to this hue matrix especially the numbers a,b and c in it?

Comment: which numbers are you talking about? there is a lot of information and you are not explicit enough.

Comment: All the numbers inside the matrix especially a,b and c.

Comment: Soo... what was A,B, and C? What are the original matrices you use to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lr`, `lg`, and `lb` are the luminance constants. If you compute the dot product of <`R`, `G`, `B`> with <`lr`, `lg`, `lb`> you'll get the luminance of the color. This is useful if you want to change the hue and/or saturation without changing the luminance of the color.

I don't recognize `a`, `b`, and `c` off the top of my head. They're probably chrominance (saturation)-related.

The `hueangle` is the angle you want to rotate your color. It rotates around the `R`=`G`=`B` axis. If you rotate 180° red becomes cyan, green becomes magenta, yellow becomes blue, etc.

You might find the [Gamma FAQ](http://www.poynton.com/notes/colour_and_gamma/GammaFAQ.html) useful, as it describes a lot of these concepts. And [this page](http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/) describes the math behind rotating around an arbitrary axis.

Also, you generally want a 4x4 matrix for color conversion, not 5x5.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will find out what led to the numbers a,b and c according to your tips.